# Set up for inter-continental database sharing and access

Tags: database, share

We have 2 offices, one in Europe and the other in South East Asia sharing a common Microsoft AX database (MSSQL). The database server is in Europe and any query done is unbearably slow. I think one major cause is the network bandwidth at 10mbps downlink and 768kbps uplink. But I don't think upgrading bandwidth is the only solution.

May I know what do MNCs do to tackle this issue? What are the technical terms i can google for more information on this?

Comment: The term you're looking for is replication - you end up with multiple database servers sharing the same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are thinking of is called database replication; [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337389.aspx) is a MSDN link for SQL 2008R2 on how to set it up.